# Ruby on rails: Basic hello world return method not allowed in Heroku production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, cloud

I am really new in rails, I am currently doing the rails tutorial in Cloud9.

I did a simple endpoint to test my lovely `Hello World` in the default `ApplicationController`. This is my controller:

ApplicationController

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  def hello
    render html: "hello, world"
  end
end
```

It works perfectly fine:
[image: Hello world]

But when I deploy the project in Heroku,  it returns `method not allowed.`

[image: Method not allowed]

Any Idea what I am doing wrong?
This are the other important files that I have

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',        '5.1.2'
gem 'puma',         '3.9.1'
gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.6'
gem 'uglifier',     '3.2.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.2.2'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.3.1'
gem 'turbolinks',   '5.0.1'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.7.0'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',      '1.3.13'
  gem 'byebug', '9.0.6', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '3.5.1'
  gem 'listen',                '3.0.8'
  gem 'spring',                '2.0.2'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.20.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root 'application#hello'
end
```

Also before I push to Heroku I did

```
> bundle update
> bundle install --without production
```

Comment: can you get the stacktrace and add it?

Comment: did you run your bundle commands on Heroku or just locally?

Comment: also, run your .appliation locally with `rails s -e production` and see if it gives same error

Comment: @kiddorails I add all the changes and commit it. If i run git add it says that there are no changes to commit.
And with the other comment, I run `rails s -e production` and now I had 500 when I do the request, here is the message. `#<RuntimeError: Missing 'secret_key_base' for 'production' environment, set this value in 'config/secrets.yml'>`

Comment: I think you're accessing your application through the wrong url, the git address is just for git. I would have thought vast-cove-xxx.herokuapp.com would do it, but it says there's no application, so I'm not sure.

Comment: @ruby_newbie I run bundle commands in Cloud9 console. Then I push to Heroku

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well thanks to Max Pleaner I realized that I was trying to connect to a wrong URL... I know, not very clever. The thing is that when I push to Heroku it said:

`remote: Verifying deploy.... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/vast-cove-65343.git`

But well, the right URL was 
https://rails-tutorial-hello-mauri.herokuapp.com/

I got this from my Heroku account, clicking in **Open App** option.

Thank you Max